# How to allocate proper bin values for the given data in a txt file to plot histogram

Tags: python, histogram

I have a set of data in my text file. I am not sure how I should consider my bin values in order to plot the histogram using matplotlib in python. Moreover, I am getting some weird king of magnitudes.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib
    f= np.loadtxt('load.txt', delimiter=',', unpack= True)
    # set bins' interval for your data
    # You have following intervals: 
    # 1st col is number of data elements in [0,10000);
    # 2nd col is number of data elements in [10000, 20000); 
    # ...
    # last col is number of data elements in [100000, 200000]; 
    #bins = [0,10000,20000,50000,100000,200000] 
    bins = [0,50,100,150,200]
    plt.hist(f, histtype = 'bar', bins = bins)
    plt.xlabel('x values')
    plt.ylabel('y values')
    plt.title('Random plot')
    #plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

---

```
    data:
    1,100
    2,10
    3,50
    4,110
    5,120
    6,200
```

Comment: What is the question exactly? See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question.

Comment: I see that you have included your code and some example input but can you give your expected output so that we can compare with the created output?